# Xcode constraints is pushing everything on the view to the very top (behind navigation bar)

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I'm hoping someone can help me out here. I set where I want the items to be using constraints and when I run and build the app it seems to push everything to the top. This occurs even when I don't put any constraints on any items. I've attached pictures if they help at all.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/POFJo.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6lBz.png]

Comment: Have you got any warnings/errors in your storyboard?

Comment: The only one that I can see that is out of the ordinary is "Main.storyboard: warning: Unsupported Configuration: Plain Style unsupported in a Navigation Item"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a solution. Somal was on the right track in terms of the Top Layout Guide. I simply had to right click each individual object to drag onto the view and select Vertical Spacing to Top Layout Guide (See picture) or I could of simply delete the entire ViewController and start from scratch with no copying and pasting from the old View.

[VerticalSpacingMenu-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9POP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the Top Constraint of your topmost subview to "Top Layout Guide" as seen in this screenshot? (Looks like your Top constraint is to the 'Superview' instead!)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpHAQ.png

Comment: Yeah that might be the problem. How could I fix that? Thanks

Comment: As per AMAN77's answer below you can first clear constraints.  
And the square constraint button in bottom right of your screen will open a popup window as in this screenshot:  
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdom0.png  
  
Which you can use to set the values for top/left/right/bottom padding, and also for the item's own width and height too.  

Hope this helps!  
PS: If this answer helps, please don't forget to accept my answer above.   Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Making sure your view is selected go click  on the triangle constraint button in the bottom right and select clear constraints under all views.
Place the views where you want them. Then for each element click the square constraint button on the bottom right and do this:

- Uncheck constrain to margins
- Pin to top bottom and both sides
- Check width and height

Then select the triangle and choose update frames for selected view.
Fine tune position by by selecting the view you want to move and updating the constraint value.

Because sometimes its just easier to start again than to try and fix constraints.